# Maximum value of K

Tags: number-theory

Writing down all the integers from $19$ to $92 $ I have made a large integer , $N=19202122\cdot\cdot\cdot92$ .

If N is divisible by $3^k$ then what is the maximum value of K ?

My try :

I have tried to add the digits of this number , but could not able to solve this problem .

Comment: Sum of digits (taken two at a time) is a good approach, should give you the answer, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $100 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $100 \equiv 1 \pmod 9$, we have:
$$N = \sum_{k=0}^{73} (92-k) \cdot 100^{k} \equiv \sum_{k=0}^{73} (92-k) \equiv 4107 \equiv 0 \pmod 3 $$

but similarly, we find $4107 \neq 0 \pmod 9$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the digits in your answer:
There are $10$ numbers in the twenties, $10$ in the thirties...and $10$ in the eighties.

Adding the tens digits $2+3+4+5+6+7+8=35$ and these each appear $10$ times, so the ten's digits in your number add to $350$

The units digits $0-9$ add to $45$, and these appear $7$ times, so the units digits add to $315$

Adding the digits in the numbers we haven't included yet, $19, 90, 91, 92$, we get $40$

So adding all the digits in your really big number we get $350+315+40=705$

$705$ is divisble by $3$ but ***not*** by $9$, so the same is true of your number...